# Using Python to get pixel value of a jpeg(SL4A android 4.0)

Tags: android, python, pixel, sl4a

I am working on a project on my Samsung Galaxy Tab with Android 4.0 Ice-cream sandwich.
Using python through SL4A I am trying to get the pixel RGB value of a jpeg(or png) image of a give co-ordinate (x,y).

Comment: Do you have to use SL4A instead of one of the other Python ports? Kivy's [Python for Android](http://txzone.net/2012/01/introducing-python-for-android/) comes with PIL, which will make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

The Android scripting facades do not include anything that can do this. And, as far as I know, nobody has done a port of [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm), [imageio](http://imageio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or any other popular image libraries, to SL4A.

However, Kivy's [Python for Android](http://txzone.net/2012/01/introducing-python-for-android/) distribution comes with PIL. If you can use that, great. If not, maybe you can look at how they get `_imaging.so` to build, and build it for S4LA.

If either of those works for you, this is easy:

```
jpg = PIL.Image.open('foo.jpg')
pixels = jpg.load()
r, g, b = pixels[x, y]
```

Alternatively, there are a handful of pure-Python JPEG libraries out there, such as [TonyJpegDecoder](http://davidf.sjsoft.com/files/pyjpeg/) or [NanoJPEG](https://github.com/sullerandras/nanojpeg-python). Try searching PyPI, ActiveState, and Google for more. (You may want to search for things related go Google App Engine, because GAE has similar limitations to Android.)

None of these are as complete, full-featured, or simple as PIL, the Python bindings for libjpeg, etc., and they're probably going to be very slow. (From NanoJPEG's documentation: "it needs 12 seconds to decompress a 400x400 pixel image on my core2duo machine, compared to the original C code's 0.2 seconds"…)

But you should be able to do what you need. For example (untested):

```
with open('foo.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    jpegdata = f.read()
decoder = TonyJpegDecoder.TonyJpegDecoder()
bmp = decoder.DecompressImage(jpegdata)
bmpstr = ''.join(map(cur(bmp)))
bmprgb = bgr2rgb(bmpstr)
pos = y * decoder.Width + x
rgb = map(ord, bmprgb[pos*3:(pos+1)*3])
```

Note that many libraries that claim to be "pure Python" just mean that they're wrapping a C library via `ctypes` instead of using an extension module, which won't directly help in this case—but it may be easier to port something like libjpeg or FreeImage than PIL. (In fact, it may just be a matter of "make a generic recipe, run the build script, and push, if you're lucky.)

As a truly crazy possibility, [PySide](http://thp.io/2011/pyside-android/) was ported to Android long before PIL, so you could always use Qt to do the image manipulation for you. But honestly, it has to be easier to port PIL or imageio or at least libjpeg.